# C# - How to split,replace the content of xml file?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a xml file:

```
<xml ?iwes sf>
    <product>
        <name> Computer </name>
        <details>a product of Dell</details>
        <sender> sender no name</sender>
    </product>
</xml>
```

i want split to:

```
<xml ?iwes sf>,     ,<product>,         ,<name>,Computer,</name>,...,    ,</xml>
```

Then i translate text content (Computer,a product of Dell, sender no name) to Korean Language.
Finally, i want join

```
<xml ?iwes sf>,     ,<product>,         ,<name>,Computer,</name>,...,    ,</xml>
```

with result translated:

```
<xml ?iwes sf>
    <product>
        <name> 컴퓨터</name>
        <details>Dell의 제품 </details>
        <sender> 아니오 유명한 송신기 </sender>
    </product>
</xml>
```

i used Regex:

```
string[] gettag = Regex.Split(inputText.Text, "(<.*?>)|(.+?(?=<|$))");
```

but it's wrong, it cann't do what i want, i cann't join xml tag to  location before, cause it cann't get "\t"!
What should i do??
My English level is'ot good. I hope everyone can understand what i said and help me!
Thanks!

Comment: Did you consider a proper XML parser before regex?

Comment: Don't use RegEx for that. Use Linq or XPath.

Comment: I just split all of the file. If i split file by line i can check it.

Comment: Seem some reasons why parsing XML/HTML with regex is hard/impractical [on this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg). As germi has mention, check out [linq to xml](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/218979-linq-to-xml/) or [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @germi: Can you instructions for me?

Comment: @user3172506: Amicable posted a link to a tutorial. Check that out. If that still doesn't help, come back with your exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

y not some lambda expression ?

you can try this.

```
      IEnumerable<XElement> xx = xdoc.Root.Descendants().Elements().Where(c => { if (c.Name == "name") { c.Value = "Dell"; } else if (c.Name == "details") { c.Value = "Dell Detial"; } return true; }).Select(c => c);


            // Loop.
            string x = string.Empty;
            foreach (XElement x1 in xx)
            {
                x += x1.ToString();
            }

      Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
```